# Alpinejs fire re-init after html injection

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I use Alpine.js to fetch some html and inject it in my page. But this content has some alpine.js code inside, but it doesn't work because alpine doesn't reinit. Any way to force the reinitialization?
For example this content has a div[x-cloak] but this div doesn't show because alpine doesn't remove x-cloak

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you are using? This works on my machine. The raw response contains the x-cloak attribute, but once it is added to the target Div, the x-cloak attribute disappears. `   <button x-on:click="fetch('/GetPartial').then(response => response.text()).then(html => {document.getElementById('partialTarget').innerHTML = html;})">Fetch</button>
   <div id="partialTarget"></div>`